# How do I insert data from multiple tables into one table

Tags: sql, create-table

This is the question:

> Using the SQL CREATE TABLE statement, create a table, MOVSTARDIR, with attributes for the movie number, star number, and director number and the 4 acting awards. The primary key is the movie number, star number and director number (all 3), with referential integrity enforced. The director number is the director for that movie, and the star must have appeared in that movie.
>   Load MOVSTARDIR (from existing tables) using INSERT INTO.

---

This is my current solution:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVSTARDIR
(
MVNUM SHORT NOT NULL,
STARNUM SHORT NOT NULL,
DIRNUM SHORT NOT NULL,
BESTF TEXT,
BESTM TEXT,
SUPM TEXT,
SUPF TEXT
);

ALTER TABLE MOVSTARDIR ADD CONSTRAINT PrimeKey PRIMARY KEY(MVNUM, STARNUM, DIRNUM)

INSERT INTO MOVSTARDIR
SELECT MOVIE.MVNUM, STAR.STARNUM, DIRECTOR.DIRNUM, BESTF, BESTM, SUPF, SUPM
FROM MOVIE, STAR, DIRECTOR, MOVSTAR, MOVDIR
WHERE MOVSTAR.MVNUM = MOVIE.MVNUM
AND MOVDIR.MVNUM = MOVSTAR.MVNUM
AND MOVDIR.DIRNUM = DIRECTOR.DIRNUM
```

My issue is that the created table is still blank.  How do I fill it up with the required data?

Comment: Does your `select` query return any data? Have you commit the transaction after `insert` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVSTARDIR AS
(SELECT MOVIE.MVNUM, STAR.STARNUM, DIRECTOR.DIRNUM, BESTF, BESTM, SUPF, SUPM
FROM MOVIE, STAR, DIRECTOR, MOVSTAR, MOVDIR
WHERE MOVSTAR.MVNUM = MOVIE.MVNUM
AND MOVDIR.MVNUM = MOVSTAR.MVNUM
AND MOVDIR.DIRNUM = DIRECTOR.DIRNUM)
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Check if the select returns any data

For testing you don't need it to return the complete data.
Just include a WHERE clause to test for a smaller resultset.

---

Step 2 : Make sure that the expected result of that select is correct.

---

Step 3.1 : do the insert from the select into the new table

---

Step 3.2:

If autocommit is turned on for your session, and there was no error.
Then those records should be in the new table.

If autocommit is off, then you still need to COMMIT your changes.
For example [this older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385655/what-does-commit-do)

---

**Remark:**

Your query is still using the older style to join tables.
Better use the current standard [JOIN syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).
It has better readability.
And it becomes more obvious which join conditions are missing.
You don't desire a [cartesian join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) by accident.

For example:

```
SELECT 
MOVIE.MVNUM, STAR.STARNUM, DIRECTOR.DIRNUM, BESTF, BESTM, SUPF, SUPM
FROM MOVIE 
JOIN MOVSTAR ON MOVSTAR.MVNUM = MOVIE.MVNUM
LEFT JOIN STAR ON STAR.STARNUM = MOVSTAR.STARNUM
LEFT JOIN MOVDIR ON MOVDIR.MVNUM = MOVSTAR.MVNUM
LEFT JOIN DIRECTOR ON DIRECTOR.DIRNUM = MOVDIR.DIRNUM
```

Please notice that a join on STAR was included.
Without knowing the tables, that's of course just an assumption.
But you get the idea.