# What does COMMIT do?

Tags: sql, oracle, commit

What is the difference between the following statements:

```
insert into table_name values (,,,,,);
```

And:

```
insert into table_name values (,,,,,);
commit;
```

Comment: both the statements insert the record into database but commit basically commit the record into database, so that others can see the change.

Comment: Moreover, after logout all not commited changes are gone

Comment: @rzysia the behaviour depends on the tool. Some auto commit on disconnect.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [the Oracle documentation for the COMMIT statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4010.htm#SQLRF01110) which clearly states what happens when a COMMIT is performed. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you insert data without commit you can select data from database and see it. But other users can't.

It's better to look to sql documentation:

> Until you commit a transaction:
>
> You can see any changes you have made during the transaction by
>   querying the modified tables, but other users cannot see the changes.
>   After you commit the transaction, the changes are visible to other
>   users' statements that execute after the commit.
>
> You can roll back (undo) any changes made during the transaction with
>   the ROLLBACK statement (see ROLLBACK.

for example here [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm)
and some info about [transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT016)

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  I've *never* used a commit statement, and people are always able to see my changes.

Answer (score 3):

All the DML (insert, update , delete) to be inserted in the database you have to commit them, like approve that you want to add them in the database. If you dont commit DML statment , it will not be enter in the database.

what is commit ?

[Docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm) cant describe it better

> Use the COMMIT statement to end your current transaction and make
>   permanent all changes performed in the transaction. A transaction is a
>   sequence of SQL statements that Oracle Database treats as a single
>   unit.  his statement also erases all savepoints in the transaction and
>   releases transaction locks.